# How can i get any element class/id from live website to my local website using Jsoup?

Tags: html, jsoup

how can i get data any element from live website in internet and parsing to my local html using Jsoup?

Comment: You want to "parse a 3rd party website to your local html"? Sorry, this is completely unclear to me. Please explain what you want to do. Also, post your code to achieve this and the problems you are facing. Right now (unedited) I vote to close this.

Comment: i just imagine... i have no code or anything.... its little bit i want to make experiment... but i confused...is it able to get any element like id or class from live website on internet?

Comment: okay, no code. But still please express what you want to achieve in more words. I simply don't get it. Give definitions of of what you mean be "local html". You mean the DOM representation in memory that JSoup creates? Or do you run a webserver locally and want to copy over stuff from the "live website" you mention? Just use a couple of more sentences and people may understand what you try to do

Comment: there is run a webserver locally and want to copy over stuff from the "live website" how can i do that???